# SUMA DE VARIABLES

Tags: php

con este código genero una tabla la cual en el campo "a tiempo" tiene el valor uno, como hago para sumar esos 1. Quiero sacar un total de las que están a tiempo y de las que no están a tiempo.
Y una vez que tenga los totales sacar un porcentaje.

```
<tr class="<?php echo $estilo?>">
<td><?php echo $close;?></td>
<td><?php echo $p1[0]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo count ($if;) ?></td>
<td><?php echo count ($ia); ?></td>
</tr>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <p></p>
 <table border="1" align="center" id="tabtot">
</tr>
<tr class="bg4">
  <th>SOLICITO</th>
  <th>MATERIAL</th>
  <th>FUERA DE TIEMPO</th>
  <th>A TIEMPO</th>
</tr>
 <?php

//////////////////////////////////////////MATERIAL//////////////////////////////////////////////////

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT idpedido, fechac, hora FROM comentarios WHERE fechac>='$fecha1' AND fechac<='$fecha2' AND tipo='6' GROUP BY idpedido ASC ORDER BY fechac,hora ASC ");

 $contador =mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($contador!=0)
{
    while ($array=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT idpedido, fecha, hora FROM pedido WHERE fecha>='$fecha1' AND fecha<='$fecha2' GROUP BY idpedido ASC ORDER BY fecha,hora ASC  ");
        while ($array2=mysql_fetch_array($query2))
        {       
            if($array[0]==$array2[0] )
            {           
                    //SELECT AVG(nota) AS nota FROM notas;  <---[SACAR PROMEDIO]

                    $hcom=$array[2];
                    $hvent=$array2[2];                  

                    $hc = strtotime($hcom);
                    $hv = strtotime($hvent);

                    $hc = $hc / 60;
                    $hv = $hv / 60;

                    if($hc>$hv)
                    {
                        //$rest = $hc - $hv;
                        $datetime1 = new DateTime($hcom);
                        $datetime2 = new DateTime($hvent);
                        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $datetime1 = new DateTime($hvent);
                        $datetime2 = new DateTime($hcom);
                        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
                    } 

                    $query4 = mysql_query("SELECT idpedido, solicito, tipo FROM pedido WHERE fecha>='$fecha1' AND fecha<='$fecha2'");
                    while ($array4=mysql_fetch_array($query4))
                    {
                        if($array[0]==$array4[0])
                        {
                            $close=$array4[1];
                            $t=$array4[2];                                  
                        }
                    }

                    //////////////////////////MATERIAL/////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    $q=mysql_query("SELECT idmaterial, flisto from pedmat where idpedido='$array2[0]' and flisto='0000-00-00' GROUP BY idmaterial asc"); 
                    while ($q1=mysql_fetch_array($q))
                    {
                        $p=mysql_query("select material from material where id='$q1[0]'");
                        while ($p1=mysql_fetch_array($p))
                        {
                            $t4=240;
                            $t24=1440;
                            $hv4 = $hv + $t4;
                            $hv5 = $hv + $t24;
                            $if=0;
                            $ia=0;
                    if($p1[0]=='POLIETILENO ADS SANIPROPLUS' && $close!='INFORMACION' && $t!=1 )
                    {

                        if($hc>$hv5)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv5)
                        {
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                        }
                    }

                    if($p1[0]=='POLIETILENO ADS SANIPROPLUS' && $close=='INFORMACION' && $t==1 )
                    {

                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                        }
                    } 

                    if($q1[0]==1 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }

                    if($q1[0]==2 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                             //echo $ia;
                             //echo max($sum, -4); //returns -4
                        }   
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==5 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==6 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';  
                        }
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==9 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4 && $array[1]>$array2[1])
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4 || $array[1]<=$array2[1])
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';  
                        }
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==11 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==12 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';  
                        }
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==13 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';  
                        }
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==14 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';  
                        }
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==15 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }   

                    if($q1[0]==17 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }   

                    if($q1[0]==18 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }   

                    if($q1[0]==19 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }  

                    if($q1[0]==22 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }   

                    if($q1[0]==23 && $close!='PIEZA ESPECIAL')
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }   

                    if($q1[0]==24)
                    {
                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }   

                    if($q1[0]==8 && $close!='INFORMACION' && $t!=1 )
                    {
                        $hv4 = $hv + $t24;

                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {

                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';
                        }
                    }
                    if($q1[0]==8 && $close=='INFORMACION' && $t==1 )
                    {
                        $hv4 = $hv + $t4;

                        if($hc>$hv4)
                        {
                            $r='FUERA DE TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg1';
                            $if=$if+1;
                        }
                        elseif($hc<$hv4)
                        {
                            $ia=$ia+1;
                            $r='A TIEMPO';
                            $estilo='bg2';

                        }
                    }
                ?>
                        <tr class="<?php echo $estilo?>">
                            <td><?php echo $close;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $p1[0]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $if; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo count ($ia); ?></td>                         
                        </tr>   

                    <?php
                    }

                }
            }   
        }       
    }
 }
 else
 {
     echo "<tr><td>No hay registros</td></tr></table>";
     //Mensaje de no hay registros
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Que tal jasiel , puedes estructurar mejor tu pregunta para que la respuesta sea precisa, la tabla se llena con un bucle , si es asi coloca el código en tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: ya coloque el código solo que es muy extenso por eso no lo subí previo solo donde creo podría estar el error y la solución

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mira por que no usas variables externas al loop que te ayuden a almacenar los resultados, no coloque todo el código ya que es mucho y no te dejaria claro el punto así que me tome la molestia de colocar solo lo que necesitas aplicar, te dejo el ejemplo :

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT idpedido, fechac, hora FROM comentarios WHERE fechac>='$fecha1' AND fechac<='$fecha2' AND tipo='6' GROUP BY idpedido ASC ORDER BY fechac,hora ASC ");
 $contador =mysql_num_rows($query);

 //# Declarando las variables
 $_f_tiempo = 0;
 $_a_tiempo = 0;

 if ($contador!=0)
 {
      //.... Code - todas tus condiciones y while's
?>
                        <tr class="<?php echo $estilo?>">
                            <td><?php echo $close;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $p1[0]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $if; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo count ($ia); ?></td>                         
                            <?php
                                //Sumamos 
                                $_f_tiempo += $if; 
                                $_a_tiempo += $ia; 
                            ?>
                        </tr>  
<?php 
  //...Code - cerrando todas las condiciones y while's
 } else { 
 echo "<tr><td>No hay registros</td></tr></table>";
 }
echo "</table>";
echo "<br><br>"
echo "\"Fuera de tiempo\" total : ".$_f_tiempo;
echo "\"A tiempo\" total : ".$_a_tiempo;
?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias era lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

#### EDITADO

Estas utilizando la función `count()` en una variable de tipo numérico. Lo cual, por sintaxis, esta equivocado. `Count()` es específicamente para elementos que puedan ser contados. (arreglos, objetos, etc)

**Función count:** http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php

Por esto, lo que te recomendaría hacer es lo siguiente:

```
<tr class="<?php echo $estilo?>">
<td><?php echo $close;?></td>
<td><?php echo $p1[0]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $if; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ia; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
   if( $if > 0 ) $notAtTime++;
   if( $ia > 0 ) $atTime++;
?>
```

Donde `$notAtTime` almacena cuantos registros no están a tiempo y `$atTime` si lo están.

Comment: no me guarda nada en la variable $atTime

Comment: Si puedes especificar un contexto mejor de tus variables con gusto te lo adapto.

Comment: pues todo el código es muy largo ya que crearon muchas condiciones if , pero toma en cuenta solo las variables que van asi :$ia=ia+1 y las que van $if=if+1 esas variables son las que quiero sumar o contar . para generar mi tabla que puse hice una consulta por rango de fechas , asi me muestra por mes las entras a tiempo y fuera de tiempo

Comment: en base a mi tabla me arrojo lo que se observa ahora quiero sumar totales de entregas a tiempo y fuera de tiempo y sacar un porcentaje, pero no se como obtener los totales

Comment: He editado, aclarame si eso resuelve tu pregunta.

Comment: pero no se me muestran los totales ya lo puse como indicas, ya acomodo todo en la tabla.  en la imagen de mi tabla se muestran 12 entregas a tiempo y quiero que aparezca así el 12 debajo de todos los 1

Comment: ¿Lo agregaste arriba del echo "</table>";? ¿Que te arrojan las variables $atTime y $notAtTime si haces un echo con ellas?

Comment: si esta arriba del echo "</table>"